# how to call a method before other methods

Tags: php, oop

I need to check user accessibility to a method.

when a method calling in the script I have to check if the user has access to that method or not. and if not, the method should `return false`.

I made a method named `_access()` that check accessibility.

how can I call this method before every other method.

I cant call `_access()` in  every methods by myself.

obj:

```
class foo{
    function a()
        $this->_access(); //I dont want to do this for every functions...
    }
    function b()
        //b() should stop if _access() == false
    }
    function _access()
        //return true or false;
        //this method can backtrace and check user accessibility to caller method.
    }
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: hvnt u heard of  if statements ??

Answer (score 3):

You can use magic methods in PHP 5.0+ which would allow you to hide methods and run a script prior.

[Read about magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php)

```
class foo{
   public function __call ( string $name , array $arguments )
   {
        if($this->_access)
           $name($arguments);
        else
           echo "User does not have access";
   }

    private function a(){}
    private function b(){}
    private function _access()
        //return true or false;
    }
}
```

## Edit

---

You could implement this fairly easily across all of your classes by making it a base class and then extending.

```
class BaseMethodAccess{
   public function __call ( string $name , array $arguments )
   {
        if($this->_access)
           $name($arguments);
        else
           echo "User does not have access";
   }

    private function _access()
        //return true or false;
    }
}

class Foo extends BaseMethodAccess{
   private function getName(){}
}
```

You can also implement the `__get` method to modify access to properties.

Comment: this is a good idea... but my site have hundred methods. not good enough in my site. thanks...

Comment: I change my mind. how to trigger __call() on public functions?

Comment: You cannot trigger on public functions.  The function must be inaccessible before the magic method is invoked, so that means either the method need to be private, or it needs to not exist by the name called.

Comment: and another thing that happened in real script is when I try to call function inside __call() the script get in a loop.

Comment: I might have written my code with too many `$` characters.  Try with only one `$name($arguments)`.  If that doesn't work and you plan to instantiate the class try `$this->$name($arguments)` instead.